# Check if a file is executable(binary/shared objects/shell script, etc) without checking the executable permissions

Tags: python, linux, bash, file, rpm

I'm trying to generate the HMAC of some files that goes in a RPM. I have to generate the HMAC for only those files that are binaries/executable during build time and package these generated HMAC as a separate RPM. I have to do this for every RPM that goes in a system and hence the only way I see is to use the %_os_install_post macro where I loop inside the RPM_BUILD_ROOT and find out all the files inside RPM_BUILD_ROOT and generate HMAC where applicable - all this should be done while invoking the rpmbuild command. The question is while looping inside the RPM_BUILD_ROOT how do I differentiate whether a file is binary/executable or not? Checking the executable permission of the file is not working because some of the files don't have their 'x' permission set in the RPM_BUILD_ROOT of the build machine but they have the permission set when the RPM gets installed.

I tried using the file utility as well but the problem with it is that since it checks the encoding inside the file, shell scripts are categorized as "text".

What are the other options? I'm mainly looking for suggestions using bash or python.

Here is what I've tried -

```
find \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT -print| while read x;\
do\
    python $topdir/check_bin_gen_hmac.py \$x $topdir\
           \$RPM_BUILD_ROOT $arch;\
done;\
%{nil}
```

The check_bin_gen_hmac.py is the script that should generate the HMAC after checking if a file is binary/executable.

Comment: I'm guessing you can't rely on file extension? You could try to access the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) from the file. There's a Python package to help with this https://pypi.org/project/python-magic

Comment: Sorry - just read that you tried to use the file utility, which is basically what I suggested. If `file` reports shell scripts as text then the script is missing a shebang.

Comment: Yes some of the shell scripts might miss shebang. File extensions can range to anything as I'm doing this for every RPM that goes into the production system.

Comment: Scripts without shebang are arguably not executables, but instead data files for shells. They are not executable in the normal execve sense. If you still want to count them, how about installing in a chroot and seeing what ends up with +x

Comment: If you have shell scripts without shebang lines, I'd think the best solution would be to add shebangs to them. This is generally good practice, and would also let `file` recognize them as executable.

Comment: @thatotherguy Installing in a chroot is actually a good suggestion only if it doesn't require me have access to the spec file of the RPM(reason being I'm doing it for every RPM in a system and altering every spec of RPM is out of scope).  Would you please point me to some resources that will help me out on how to do that?

Comment: @GoutamBose It depends on the distro. Some have simple ways of setting up a chroot, some don't. You can also use Docker, which has images for most distros. You don't need to modify anything, just install the RPM in such a container (or a real system if you're already doing that), and use the `rpm` functionality for querying installed files and seeing which ones ended up with `+x`